# 'Generating code' and stop in building release mode (Visual Studio 2005 )

Tags: visual-studio-2005, mfc, compilation, release-mode

I have a problem about release build

I'm using Visual Studio 2005. The project is worked on MFC

When I build the project what I working in debug mode, It builds done successfully.
but in release mode, Output window shows next

1>Compiling resources...
1>Linking...
1>Generating code

and then.. it doesn't pass.
It seems like be stoped.
After 20 min ,I just canceld build.

It has been built well before.
I just added some files(.h .cpp) and resorces(.bmp), not special code
and it happened.

Do you have any idea about that?
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Start a Windows Update, and when Windows Update recommends switching to Microsoft Update, do it.  Microsoft Update will download hundreds of megabytes of patches for your Visual Studio installation.

Comment: Did you tell Windows Update to switch over to Microsoft Update?  And there was still nothing?  You already received those hundreds of megabytes of patches and Visual Studio still has this problem?  If you have a repro on this, you should post to a Microsoft site.  By the way I get occasional hangs too but the last time I had a reproducible case was many patches ago.